# CATiledlayer setContents nil give me a crash

Tags: objective-c, crash, catiledlayer, setneedsdisplay

I have a uiview with CATiledlayer.  I want to reuse the view, so I wrote:

```
self.layer.contents = nil; 
[self.layer setNeedDisplay];
```

but I got a random crash.  Stack trace follows:

```
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3929908c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x391f4f19 pthread_cond_wait + 41
2 QuartzCore 0x32d3b205 CAImageProviderSetCallback + 189
3 QuartzCore 0x32dc600d -[CATiledLayer setContents:] + 73
4 TBClient 0x000933ed -[TBRichTextView drawRichTextContent] (TBRichTextView.m:114)
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: oh,It crash at :self.layer.contents = nil;  I know that catiledlayer
 can't change the conetents when the layer is drawing,but how can make
sure it?